# Power Automate condition not working for filtering files

Tags: conditional-statements, power-automate

I have a flow that copies files correctly, but when I add a condition to filter the files to be copied, I get an *ActionBranchingConditionNotSatisfied* error in the *Copy Files* action.

I have tried changing the *File Identifier*, relocating the condition in the flow, adding an array filter, and adding the *Get File Content* action, all without success.

Is there another action I should add to the flow that the condition should use?

Thanks for any advice!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some example data so we can recreate to as close as you’ve got it?

Comment: Thanks @Skin - I tried to create a Scope to share, but once I'd removed the confidential links (URLs etc.) it started giving errors. So I'm not too sure what data I can provide. :-(

Comment: Just wondering if this might be a time-out issue - I am also having problems getting conditions to work in another flow. Does anyone have experience with that?

Comment: We’d need some data and then we can try and recreate.